# How to center an element to the position of the mouse with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

So I have this box that I would like to follow the mouse when I move the mouse around but would like the mouse to always be in the center of the box.  I don't mean the box has to but literally under the box but what I mean is to have the box ONLY move vertically up and down to be inline with the mouse.

I tried several ways but couldn't get it to work and when I did for a bit it didn't center properly.

Here is my JS:

```
$( ".wrapper" ).mousemove(function(e) {
    var box = $( '.box' ).outerHeight();

    box = box / 2;

    $( '.box' ).css( 'top', ( e.pageY - box ) + 'px' );
} );
```

Here is a fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/rCabj/

Thanks!

Comment: @jqueryrocks: have a look at the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `top` to `marginTop`.

```
 $( '.box' ).css('marginTop', ( e.pageY - box ) + 'px' );
```

***[The demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/rCabj/3/)***

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/rCabj/1/

on the .box

```
position: absolute;
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing CSS to position: absolute solves the problem